# Ошибка сегментирования где-то в sort

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Добрый день!

Падает программа с ошибкой сегментирования
написал 2 варианта программы, ошибку найти не могу

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using std::vector;
using std::string;



bool is_ge(string digit1, string digit2){
  std::cout << "Input compare" << digit1 << " " << digit2 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Input compare size" << digit1.size() << " " <<   digit2.size() << std::endl;
  bool  result = true;
  for(int i = 0; i < std::min(digit1.length(), digit2.length()); ++i){
  std::cout << "Debug: " << digit1.size() << " " << digit2.size() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Debug: " << digit1[i] << " " << digit2[i] << std::endl;
  if(digit1[i] > digit2[i]){
    std::cout << "cool" << std::endl; 
    break;
  } else if(digit1[i] < digit2[i]){
    std::cout << "bad" << std::endl; 
    result = false;
    break; 
  }
   std::cout << "Debug2: " << digit1[digit1.size() - i] << " " << digit2[digit2.size() - i] << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "exit of compare" << std::endl;
  return result;
}




string largest_number(vector<string> &a) {
  sort(a.begin(), a.end(), is_ge);
  std::cout << " bla" << std::endl;
  std::stringstream ret;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
      ret << a[i];
  }
  string result;
  ret >> result;
  std::cout << "result :" << std::endl;
  return result;
}
```

Причем падает где-то в сорт... Написал такую же версию без сорт - все равно падает, а где - понять не могу. В чем ошибка и как вообще отлаживать и ловить такие вещи?

Использую гцц.

```
int main() {
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  vector<string> a(n);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
      std::cin >> a[i];
  }

  std::cout << largest_number(a);
}
```

Второй код, где все падает:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>



using std::vector;
using std::string;



bool is_ge(string digit1, string digit2){
  std::cout << "Input compare" << digit1 << " " << digit2 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Input compare size" << digit1.size() << " " <<     digit2.size() << std::endl;
  bool  result = true;
  for(int i = 0; i < std::min(digit1.length(), digit2.length()); ++i){
    std::cout << "Debug: " << digit1.size() << " " << digit2.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Debug: " << digit1[i] << " " << digit2[i] << std::endl;
    if(digit1[i] > digit2[i]){
      std::cout << "cool" << std::endl; 
      break;
    } else if(digit1[i] < digit2[i]){
      std::cout << "bad" << std::endl; 
      result = false;
      break; 
    }
    std::cout << "Debug2: " << digit1[digit1.size() - i] << " " << digit2[digit2.size() - i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "exit of compare" << std::endl;
    return result;
 }




string largest_number(vector<string> &a) {
  sort(a.begin(), a.end(), is_ge);
  std::cout << " bla" << std::endl;
  std::stringstream ret;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    ret << a[i];
  }
  string result;
  ret >> result;
  std::cout << "result :" << std::endl;
  return result;
 }





int main() {
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  vector<string> a(n);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    a[i] = std::to_string(rand() % 10 + 1);
  }
  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << a[i] << "  ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << largest_number(a);
}`
```

падает на размере 100 точно.
Второй код - это вводишь размер и все, в отличии от первого

С сортом понятно, а почему падает без сорта следующий код?:

```
string largest_number(vector<string> &a) {
  string str;
  int j;
  std::stringstream ret;
  while(a.size() > 0){
    str = a[0];
  for(j = 0; j < a.size(); ++j){
     if(is_less(str, a[j])){
     std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
     str = a[j];
     } 
   }
   ret << a[j];
   std::cout << "Test1" << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Test3 " << std::endl;
   a.erase(a.begin() + j);
   std::cout << "Test2" << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << " bla" << std::endl;
  string result;
  ret >> result;
  std::cout << "result :" << std::endl;
  return result;
}
```

при компараторе таком:

```
bool is_less(string digit1, string digit2){
 std::cout << "Input compare" << digit1 << " " << digit2 << std::endl;
 std::cout << "Input compare size" << digit1.size() << " " << digit2.size() << std::endl;
 bool  result = true;
 for(int i = 0; i < std::min(digit1.length(), digit2.length()); ++i){
    std::cout << "Debug: " << digit1.size() << " " << digit2.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Debug: " << digit1[i] << " " << digit2[i] << std::endl;
    if(digit1[i] < digit2[i]){
      std::cout << "cool" << std::endl; 
      return false;
    } else if(digit1[i] > digit2[i]){
      std::cout << "bad" << std::endl; 
      return true;
      break; 
    }
    std::cout << "Debug2: " << digit1[digit1.size() - i] << " " << digit2[digit2.size() - i] << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "exit of compare" << std::endl;
  return false;
 }
```

Идея такая - я нахожу максимальный элемент в векторе, кидаю его в стрингстрим, а из вектора удаляю. И так до нулевого размера вектора.

Comment: Дайте конкретный пример, на чем падает - просто я, например, падения у себя не добился...

Comment: Падает на размере 100. Добавил второй код, где есть автогенерация вектора.

Comment: @Ivan: А где именно падает этот новый код?

Comment: @Ivan: У вас должно падать `digit1[digit1.size() - i]` при `i == 0`. Отнимайте ещё единицу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, ваша сортировка падает потому, что функция сравнения не является полностью упорядочивающей функцией. Ваша функция не принимает во внимание «хвост» более длинной строки.

Кроме того, ваша функция (пытается) делать нестрогое сравнение, а нужно строгое.

Например, если сравнивать `""` и `"a"`, она выдаёт `true`, но если сравнивать их в обратном порядке (`"a"` и `""`), она тоже выдаёт `true`. Это ошибка.

Ну и сравнение строки с самой собой тоже выдаёт `true`, и это тоже ошибка.

Исправьте эти ошибки, должно заработать.

Например, можно написать такой алгоритм (лексикографическое сравнение):

1. Для индексов от 0 до минимума из длин, если `a[i] < b[i]` вернуть `true`, а если `a[i] > b[i]` вернуть `false`.
2. Если длина `a` меньше длины `b`, вернуть `true`, если длина `a` больше длины `b`, вернуть `false`.
3. В противном случае строки равны, вернуть `false`.

(Кстати, сравнение строк через `<` должно давать тот же результат.)

---

Документация: (http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.sorting#3 и дальше):

> [3] ... `comp` shall induce a strict weak ordering on the values.
>
> [4] The term strict refers to the requirement of an irreflexive relation (`!comp(x, x)` for all `x`)

---

На пальцах, почему `std::sort` падает? Когда он ищет по массиву элементы меньше некоторого элемента, то этот самый элемент попадает в список элементов, которые меньше себя. Например, если мы используем quicksort в реализации [отсюда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8), то в цикле разбиения есть такая часть:

```
while (A[i] < pivot)
    i++;
```

Для нормальных, хороших функций сравнения этот цикл обязательно завершается, натыкаясь на элемент `pivot` в цикле. Но если сравнение `pivot` с собой даёт `true`, как в вашем случае, этот цикл не останавливается на `pivot`, и значит, может бежать до выхода за границу массива.

Comment: Да, но автор пишет *Написал такую же версию без сорт - все равно падает*...

Comment: @Harry: Ну я ориентировался на код в вопросе. Если другой код падает — в нём другая ошибка.

Comment: Насчет сравнения - я пишу код жадного алгоритма, что на вход мне даются строки - числа, на выходе мне нужно самое большое число, которое составлено из этих чисел, т.е. сравнив 32 и 5 - 5 для меня больше.

Comment: @Ivan: Ну у вас в коде из обновления вопроса тоже есть вызов `std::sort` с неправильным компаратором. Так что причина ровно та же.

Comment: @VladD спасибо!

Comment: @Ivan: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!